# Showing images in sequence with two seconds interval time in android

Tags: android, image, imageview, sleep

I am having three images. I need to show these images one by one with 2 seconds time interval. How to achieve this concept? Suggestions please..

Thanks for your precious time !

Answer (score 1):

As far as I got you, you need:

1) [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) class to show Images
  [Here is a good tutorial for it](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/)

and

2) Sleep for 2 seconds interval time.